# passing model from controller to view with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to pass model from controller to view with jQuery ajax on button click. I have data on server side but jQuery ajax returns this error:

'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)'

```
` $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("userData", "Account")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            Do Something
        },
        error: function ( error) {
           alert(error.Message);
        }
   });

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult userData()
    {
        var _userData = db.userInfos.ToList();
        var result = new
        {
            MyUserData= _userData 
        };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using post and not get?

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) means the code inside your action method is crashing. Put a breakpoint inside that method and find out which line is crashing